# Python script to fetch an executable file from local repository git

Tags: c, git, python-2.7

I have an access to the local repository (git) of my company with this url -> "gitolite@10.10.10.55:/Intel/BareRepos/lteue.git" and my python script need to execute any file (.c & .h files) of this project and create a binary. After which the script has to run this binary file.
The code which I have wrote is:

```
import os
os.system("git clone gitolite@10.10.10.55:/Intel/BareRepos/lteue.git")
os.system("cd /home/saicharan/Documents/lteue")
os.system("gcc somefile.c")
os.system("./a.out")
```

I am getting the error like this

```
gcc: error: helloworld.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error:no input files compilation terminated.
sh: ./a.out: No such file or directory
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: So what is the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: To compile C sources, you need a C compiler. For the specific C compiler on your site, there should be a manual (local or in Web).

Comment: @manju-shahrukh StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service. Show us you research effort. See [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: `system("cd ...")` makes no sense. `cd` only affects the current process, which is the subshell spawned by `system`, which exits immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I got the solution for this:

```
os.system("git clone gitolite@10.10.10.55:/Intel/BareRepos/lteue.git")

os.chdir("path/to/file")
os.system("gcc path/to/file/somefile.c")

os.chdir("path/to/file")
os.system("./somefile.out")
```

and its working fine.!

Answer (score 0):

You can make it even more simpler.

```
import os

os.system("git clone gitolite@10.10.10.55:/Intel/BareRepos/lteue.git")

os.chdir("path/to/file")
os.system("gcc path/to/file/somefile.c && ./somefile.out")
```

It Works.!